# MQSendMessage() failed with MQ_ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER (0xC00E0006)

Tags: winapi, msmq, win32-process

Problem with MSMQ configuration or code i've implemented??

I've written windows service code (win32 C++ ) in which i am sending a log to the local private queue.This code is working fine if I execute that in 32-bit environment (either windows7/8/vista). But that same code if I build for x64 OS and if I execute MQSendMessage() failed with MQ_ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER (0xC00E0006). What could be the problem.??? Please help me out in this regard.Thanks in advance..

I've tried by changing the NUMBEROFPROPERTIES  from 3-7 in x-64 windows 7 system. But still the problem remains same. what to do to avoid this..

Here is my sample code

```
#define ClientQueue L".\\Private$\\TestQueue"
#define LogMsgLable L"TestLOG"
#define MIN_PRIVATE_QUEUE_NAME_LENGTH 55

DWORD MSMQSendMessage()
{
    //Define the required constants and variables.
    const int NUMBEROFPROPERTIES = 7;                   // Number of properties
    DWORD cPropId = 0;                                  // Property counter
    HRESULT hr = MQ_OK;                                 // Return code
    HANDLE hQueue = NULL;                               // Queue handle

    //Define an MQMSGPROPS structure.
    MQMSGPROPS msgProps;
    MSGPROPID aMsgPropId[NUMBEROFPROPERTIES] = {0};
    MQPROPVARIANT aMsgPropVar[NUMBEROFPROPERTIES] = {0};
    HRESULT aMsgStatus[NUMBEROFPROPERTIES] = {0};

    // Specify the message properties to be sent.
    aMsgPropId[cPropId] = PROPID_M_LABEL;               // Property ID
    aMsgPropVar[cPropId].vt = VT_LPWSTR;                // Type indicator
    aMsgPropVar[cPropId].pwszVal = L"ADCLOG";     // The message label
    cPropId++;


    // Specifying the storage of messages in the harddisk
    // setting the message properties as recoverable

    aMsgPropId[cPropId] = PROPID_M_DELIVERY;
    aMsgPropVar[cPropId].vt = VT_UI1;
    aMsgPropVar[cPropId].bVal = MQMSG_DELIVERY_RECOVERABLE;
    cPropId++;

    aMsgPropId[cPropId] = PROPID_M_ACKNOWLEDGE;   // Property ID
    aMsgPropVar[cPropId].vt = VT_UI1;             // Type indicator
    aMsgPropVar[cPropId].bVal = MQMSG_ACKNOWLEDGMENT_FULL_RECEIVE;
    cPropId++;

    // we need to set the size of the message
    // if we dont set it, takes 4MB as default message size
    // to set the size of it we have ---> PROPID_M_BODY
    ULONG ulBufferSize = 15;
    char *lLog_msg = NULL;

    lLog_msg = ( char*)GlobalAlloc( GPTR,  15);

    ZeroMemory( lLog_msg, 15) ;

    strcpy(lLog_msg, "HelloWorld");

    aMsgPropId[cPropId] = PROPID_M_BODY;                // Property ID
    aMsgPropVar[cPropId].vt = VT_VECTOR | VT_UI1;       // Type indicator
    aMsgPropVar[cPropId].caub.pElems = (UCHAR *)lLog_msg;  // Body buffer
    aMsgPropVar[cPropId].caub.cElems = ulBufferSize;    // Buffer size
    cPropId++;

    //here we should not put VT_NULL in type as defined with VT_UI4.........
    aMsgPropId[cPropId] = PROPID_M_BODY_TYPE;           // Property ID
    aMsgPropVar[cPropId].vt = VT_UI4;                  // Type indicator
    cPropId++;

    // Initialize the MQMSGPROPS structure.
    msgProps.cProp = cPropId;
    msgProps.aPropID = aMsgPropId;
    msgProps.aPropVar = aMsgPropVar;
    msgProps.aStatus = aMsgStatus;

    // Create a direct format name for the queue.
    WCHAR *gFormatName    = NULL;
    DWORD dwBufferLength    = 0;

    dwBufferLength = MIN_PRIVATE_QUEUE_NAME_LENGTH; //Private queue format name buffer size atleast 54

    gFormatName = (WCHAR *)malloc( dwBufferLength*sizeof( WCHAR ));
    if (gFormatName == NULL)
    {
        printf( "malloc", 0, NULL );
        return MQ_ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES;
    }

    SecureZeroMemory( gFormatName, dwBufferLength*sizeof(WCHAR) );

    hr = MQPathNameToFormatName( ClientQueue,
                                 gFormatName,
                                 &dwBufferLength );
    if (FAILED( hr ))
    {
        if( hr == MQ_ERROR_FORMATNAME_BUFFER_TOO_SMALL )
        {
            if (gFormatName != NULL)
            {
                gFormatName = (WCHAR *)realloc( gFormatName, dwBufferLength*sizeof( WCHAR ));
                if (gFormatName == NULL)
                {
                    printf( "realloc failed\n");
                    return MQ_ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES;
                }                
            }

            SecureZeroMemory( gFormatName, dwBufferLength*sizeof( WCHAR ));

            hr = MQPathNameToFormatName( ClientQueue,
                                 gFormatName,
                                 &dwBufferLength );
            if(FAILED( hr ))
            {
                printf(  L"MQPathNameToFormatName2 failed:%x\n", hr);

                return hr;
            }
        }
        else
        {

               printf("MQPathNameToFormatName failed:%x\n", hr);            

               return hr;
        }
    }

    // Call MQOpenQueue to open the queue with send access.
    hr = MQOpenQueue(
                   gFormatName,                     // Format name of the queue
                   MQ_SEND_ACCESS,                    // Access mode
                   MQ_DENY_NONE,                      // Share mode
                   &hQueue                            // OUT: Queue handle
                   );    

    if ( FAILED( hr ))
    {
        printf("MQOpenQueue failed:%x\n", hr);
        goto ret;
        //goto cleanup;
    }

    if( gFormatName )
        free( gFormatName );

    // Call MQSendMessage to send the message to the queue.
    hr = MQSendMessage(
                     hQueue,                          // Queue handle
                     &msgProps,                       // Message property structure
                     NULL               // Not in a transaction
                     );
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf( "MQSendMessage failed:%x\n", hr );
        MQCloseQueue( hQueue );
        goto ret;
    }

     //Call MQCloseQueue to close the queue.
    hr = MQCloseQueue(hQueue);
    if(hr != 0)
    {
        printf("MQCloseQueue failed:%x",hr);
        //goto cleanup;
        goto ret;
    }ret:
    if( lLog_msg )
    {
        GlobalFree( lLog_msg );
        lLog_msg = NULL;
    }

    return hr;
}
```

Comment: There is really only one parameter that could be wrong and it's  `msgProps`. I suggest analyzing it carefully and comparing every single value you set to the documentation.

Comment: @CareyGregory I've gone through the documentation and it seems everything was fine in the code.
Could you please check the sample code and help me out........
Thanks for your quick reply.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works on 32-bit Windows purely by chance. Take a look at this:

```
ULONG ulBufferSize = sizeof( 15);
char *lLog_msg = NULL;

lLog_msg = ( char*)GlobalAlloc( GPTR, sizeof( 15));

ZeroMemory( lLog_msg, sizeof( 15)) ;

strcpy(lLog_msg, "HelloWorld");
```

You seem to misunderstand what the `sizeof` operator does. It is a compile time operator that replaces its argument with the size of that argument. In this case, the compiler replaces `sizeof(15)` with the number `4`. Why? Because a literal constant like `15` occupies 4 bytes on a 64-bit machine. So in the code above you are allocating 4 bytes of memory and then copying 11 bytes into it, thereby corrupting memory.

To fix this, simply remove `sizeof`. The code above should look like this:

```
ULONG ulBufferSize = 15;
char *lLog_msg = NULL;     // this is pointless since you set it in the next line

lLog_msg = ( char*)GlobalAlloc( GPTR, ulBufferSize);

ZeroMemory( lLog_msg, ulBufferSize) ;

strcpy(lLog_msg, "HelloWorld");
```

Comment: I tried like this also, this code have the same problem.

Comment: @JanardhanReddy Well, that was a pretty big error. Do you have more big errors like that? I think it would be best if you looked for them yourself because that's a big part of the job of programming. If you encounter a specific result that you can't figure out, come back and ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to specify the admin queue where acks will be sent to as well if you request acknowledgement. (MQMSG_ACKNOWLEDGMENT_FULL_RECEIVE)
I would start with more simple sample and then add acknowledgement later once you have simple sample working.

Here is sample for acknowledgement where it adds both PROPID_M_ADMIN_QUEUE and PROPID_M_ACKNOWLEDGE:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/msmq/ms711369(v=vs.85)